# How to retain lazy instance in cross ref objects

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, reference, automatic-ref-counting, weak

Given two classes which reference each other and one of the refs is `weak`, how do I retain it when initialising locally? This is the structure of the code:

```
class Generator {
    weak var machine: Machine!
    
    public init(for machine: Machine) {
        self.machine = machine
    }
    
    func start() {
        // ... code to start the generator
    }
    
    func generate() {
        machine.didGenerate(value: 1)
    }
}


class Machine {
    public lazy var generator: Generator = Generator(for: self)
    
    func start() {
        generator.start()
    }
    
    func didGenerate(value: Float) {
        // Use the value here
    }
}
```

The following usage works (example given in MacOS environment):

```
let machine = Machine()

func viewDidLoad {
    machine.start()
}
```

However this is not working:

```
func viewDidLoad {
    let machine = Machine()
    machine.start()
}
```

The `machine` reference in the `Generator` class is not retained.
How can I retain it?

Tried to use `unowned` instead of `weak`, but not working too.

Comment: `machine` goes out of scope in your last example. So nothing is holding a reference to it anymore. What´s wrong with the first scenario?

Comment: @burnsi Occasionally I need the second scenario to solve some various different "machines"

Comment: Could you not use a delegate instead of having the 2 objects referencing each other ?

Comment: @Petar Isn't a delegate also need to be defined `weak` to avoid leak on deinit?

Comment: @NikoDiYana That is correct but it is clearer to show the intention of the relationship between the 2 objects. What you are asking is impossible - as burnsi said if the weak instance goes out of scope then it will be deallocated. You could rethink your design so that it relies more on composition

Comment: @Petar Thanks, I will try to avoid the second scenario for now. But in general, could this out of scope deallocation case be considered as a Swift ease of use limitation? (Of course considering the positive side of precise memory management)

Comment: This is not a Swift-specific problem - its a general programming concept that is present in other languages as well. As I said you should rethink your design, or instead you could post more of your code and I could try to give you a suggestion.